# perl - how do I capture a multicast [video] stream?

Tags: perl, udp, multicast

I am trying to record a multicast stream coming from a webcam, and record it to a file. I can access the multicast stream and see my video with VLC, but I can't see anything when I try to play the file I'm writing via Perl.

Here's my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::Multicast;

my $group = shift @ARGV;
my $port  = shift @ARGV;

# Set up the stream
my $stream = IO::Socket::Multicast->new(Proto=>'udp', LocalPort => $port);
$stream->mcast_add($group) or die "Couldn't set group: $!\n";

# Get the date and time. We'll use this to name the stream file
my $fname = `date +%Y-%m-%dT%H_%M_%S`;
chomp $fname;
$fname .= ".mpg";

open (my $file, ">", $fname)
    or die "Couldn't open file  $fname for writing: $!";
binmode($file);

print "Streaming $group:$port to $fname!\n";

for my $i (0..500){
    my $data;
    next unless $stream->recv($data,1024);
    print "data received! $i \n";
    print {$file} $data;
}
close ($file);
```

Wireshark shows the protocol of the stream is `MPEG TS`.

I appreciate any assistance!